# C# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Requires Flash to be Installed

Tags: c#, flash, browser

When I create a form and add a WebBrowser control to it and have it navigate to http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform the flash area says I need Adobe Flash Player installed. This is already installed in IE, but apparently not in the WebBrowser control.

Is there are way to have the WebBrowser control run flash without having to manually go to the flash site and install. Flash is already installed the normal IE browser, just not the WebBrowser control in the forms app.

Comment: Not really sure but I'd take that as a security feature that the WebBrowser control does't load all ActiveX controls installed automatically.

Comment: If I can programmatically load Flash into the WebBrowser control, this would be fine also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I actually clicked on the "Get ADOBE FLASH PLAYER" link, it brings me to a page that says:

> Adobe Flash Player is not supported
>   for playback in a 64-bit browser.
>   However, you can run Flash Player in a
>   32-bit browser running on a 64-bit
>   operating system.

I changed the CPU type of the project to x86 and Flash now works just fine.